# Using Enums as properties in Domain with MSSQL Dialect

Tags: sql-server, grails, enums, grails-orm

This is a `grails 2.4.4` application. Most of the time, I work with `MySQL` and this always just works. It also works with `H2`. I'm only running into this problem with `MSSQL` as the database engine.

I have the following Enum:

```
enum RenewalStatuses {

    RETRIEVAL_COMPLETE('Retrieval Complete'),
    STAGING_COMPLETE('Staging Complete'),
    XML_COMPLETE('XML Complete'),
    SUBMIT_COMPLETE('Submit Complete'),
    CONVERT_FAILURE('Convert Failure'),
    SUBMIT_FAILURE('Submit Failure')

    private final value

    RenewalStatuses(String value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        value
    }
}
```

Which is used in the following Domain:

```
class RenewalStatus {

    Date currentStatusDate
    RenewalStatuses currentStatus
    String errorText

    static hasMany = [renewalStatusLogs: RenewalStatusLog]

    static constraints = {
        currentStatusDate nullable: false
        currentStatus nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 20
        errorText nullable: true, blank: false, maxSize: 200
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        currentStatusDate column: 'CurrentStatusDt'
        currentStatus column: 'CurrentStatus'
        errorText column: 'ErrorText'
    }
}
```

When I try and query for a RenewalStatus or a list of them I get the following error:

> Unknown name value [XML Complete] for enum class
>   [bla.foo.RenewalStatuses]

The `CurrentStatus` column is a `varchar` and contains the value text as defined in the enum's value property; `XML Complete, Submit Failure, etc`.

Again, I use this pattern in a lot of applications, but this is the first time with an app backed by `MSSQL`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `private final String value`?

Comment: Good catch. I'll make the change and see if that is the culprit.